# Попытки сократить код в if else

Tags: java, android

У меня в if

```
setupFragment(getString(R.string.ui_data_collection_accounts), true, FabAction.ADD_ACCOUNT);
```

и в else

```
setupFragment(getString(R.string.ui_data_collection_accounts), true, FabAction.NO_ACTION);
```

Пробую записать в одну строчку, так как здесь меняется только значение  FabAction возможно ли использовать тернарный оператор?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте например так:

```
setupFragment(getString(R.string.ui_data_collection_accounts), true, yourCondition ? FabAction.ADD_ACCOUNT : FabAction.NO_ACTION);
```

где `yourCondition` - условие, прописанное в блоке `if`.
Но вообще запихивать всё в одну строку - не очень хорошая идея, поскольку от этого страдает читаемость кода. А читать код, как известно, приходится чаще, чем писать его. Тем более, что здесь ситуация может усугубиться необходимостью выполнять горизонтальную прокрутку, что очень неудобно.

Comment: в роли `yourCondition` выступает то что я прописывал в if(myCondition) ?

Answer (score 4):

Для повышения читабельности я бы рекомендовал разбить на две строчки

```
Action act = (condition) ? FabAction.ADD_ACCOUNT : FabAction.NO_ACTION;
setupFragment(getString(R.string.ui_data_collection_accounts), true, act);
```